# No installed provisioning profiles match the installed iOS code signing keys in Xamarin using Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio, xamarin.mac

I have created a PCL project, I host Mac with Visual Studio but when run iOS project, it gives error:[image]

I tried to change in iOs building signing like below but nothing works for me. 
[image]

Please help me solve this issue.

Comment: I went through the [DOCUMENTATION](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/device_provisioning/) with  a fine tooth comb, over and over... I have 3 Provisioning Profiles: 2 work (all good), 1 doesn't. Been pulling my hair out over this for days!!! I've compared what I believe to be everything between the working and not-working solutions/profiles. Anyone else who has solutions PLEASE share. Thank you!!! I am trying to get the [Hanselman.Forms](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Hanselman.Forms) iOS working but no luck with the Provisioning Profile I created

Answer (score 19):

For iOS you need to register your app/device with Apple.

You will have to go to your [Apple developer account](http://developer.apple.com) and create a listing for your app and register the device you are testing on.

Also you will have to import your developer account into Xcode, this needs to be done because your development app also needs to be signed before it can be put on a physical device.

More information can be found in the [Xamarin documentation](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/device_provisioning/).

The excerpt is this;

- Go to Xcode and add your Apple ID (Choose *Xcode Menu* > *Preferences...*, Click the *Accounts* tab, Click the *Add (+)* button and select *Add Apple ID...* from the popup menu)

[image: Add Apple ID to Xcode]

- If you have an Apple ID that belongs to an Apple Developer Program, enter your Apple ID and password, and click the *Add* button.

[image: Enter Apple ID]

Otherwise you can click the *Join a Program* button and a web browser will be opened where you can sign-up.

Now you need to add your device to Xcode.

- Connect the device to your Mac with a USB cable
- From the *Windows* menu select *Devices*
- Select the desired iOS device from the *Devices* list on the left side of the *Devices Window*
- Highlight the *Identifier* string and copy it to the clipboard

[image: Select iOS device]

- Login to your [Apple developer account](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action)
- Click the *Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles* link (on the right)
- Click on the *Devices* link
- Click the *+* button (top right)
- Provide a name for the new device and paste the device *Identifier* that we copied above into the *UUID* field

[image: Add iOS device]

Now you have to pull the freshly created certificates to your Mac/Xcode.

- Stop Visual Studio/Xamarin Studio
- Start Xcode
- Choose *Xcode Menu* > *Preferences...*
- Click the *Accounts* tab
- Click the *View Details...* button
- Click the *Refresh icon* button in the lower left hand corner of the screen (the round arrow thingy)
- After the list of available *Provisioning Profiles* has been updated, click the *Done* button
- Exit Xcode (or leave it open if you like the sight..)
- Start Visual Studio/Xamarin Studio

Now I think you can start testing on your device. **But** if you need special iOS services (i.e. access to Game Center, iCloud, etc.) you will have to register your app as well. This is roughly a similar process as the one before this, but I will ahve to ask you to read the documentation on that or Google 'Provisioning for Application Services'. Before the post gets too long ;)

Note; this may change in the future because Apple has announced yesterday that sideloading (your own) apps (the thing you want to do here) will be free.
So if you do not have a Apple developer account yet then you may want to wait a little while.

Comment: But, I am not run my app on any physical device, I just want to run it on iOS simulator, So why I need to register app with Apple ?

Comment: Ha, overdid myself here then.. ;) What version of Xamarin.iOS are you using? There has been an issue with this, look at this blog post; http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/96832/#Comment_96832

Comment: Related some people report that you have to remove some entries from the **Entitlements.plist** more information also here; https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/117465#Comment_117465

Comment: I tried by remove Entitlements.plist but error not solved. I read the above mention blog , all are resolved it by download Xamarin Studio 5.7.1.4 , I also going to doing same but this ver not available now. Xamarin Studio 5.7.2.0 is available, I downloaded this and tried but not resolved.

Comment: I don't think you should remove the complete **Entitlements.plist**, could you please edit your question with the contents of your **Entitlements.plist** file?

Comment: Also could you provide a screenshot of the *(Build) Configuration Manager* screen in Visual Studio? It is located under the menu *Build* and then *Configuration Manager*, check if all *Platforms* are set to *iPhoneSimulator*

Comment: No, PCL and Android project set to "Any CPU" platform. Only iOS project is set to "iPhoneSimulator"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80038/discussion-between-ajay-sharma-and-gerald-versluis).

Comment: As you asked me on chat about all of mine certificates up to date. Yes, all certificates up to dates.

Comment: I got its solution.I just edit my.csproj file by hand and remove the key. Thanks for your support.

Comment: default user created in developer.apple is User role and not Agent or admin. so you should enroll in "Apple Developer Program Enrollment" and pay the money to see Above options in your profile

Answer (score 13):

I got its solution.I just edit my.csproj file by hand and remove the 'CodesignEntitlements' key. I found this solution from [here](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/39534/cant-build-ios-in-xamarin-studio-5-7-1-through-5-9) and thank you Gerald Versluis for helping me through facing this problem.

Comment: Good to hear that you have solved it! Although this 'answer' should really be a edit to your original question or at least a comment. :) Also, your link doesn't seem to work! For future reference please include the most vital parts in this answer and fix the link so other people can make use of your findings in the future!

Comment: Did the whole process multiple times and deleted all CodesignEntitlements tags in csproj and no answer the error still there : No installed provisioning profiles match the installed iOS signing identities

Answer (score 4):

The details from Gerald Versluis were helpful for me. The got me 90% of the way through the task. I was getting the same build error on Visual Studio 2015 with Mac Mini build host. The solution for me was to go back to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles in https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/create
and ENSURE that I configured a profile.

here is an image
[image]

It was only after I did that did I see a record available for download in the Accounts modal windows of the XCode preferences, as shown below. 
[image]

After I clicked "Download All" THEN the build was successful in VS 2015.

Hope this helps someone who has followed Gerald's detailed steps above, since that got me 90% there. Thank you.

Also, keep this logic in mind: I was unable to build in VS until I was able to build succcessfully in Xamarin Studio Community.

Comment: Thanks... using xcode download all was the last step i needed!