# Couldn't load memtrack (No such file or directory) error in Xamarin.Forms Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

I have a created a Xamarin.Forms application named MyFifthTry in Visual Studio 2015. When I try to deploy the MyFifthTry.Droid project on an already running emulator (Bluestacks 2), the deploy fails. There is no error in the ErrorList of Visual Studio, but Android Device Logging (logcat) gives me the following three errors:

> 1) Couldn't load memtrack (No such file or directory)
>
> 2) failed to load memtrack module: -2
>
> 3) Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

I searched the internet and SO for these errors and found many questions with answers but none of them helped me as they were all regarding Android Studio and Java, due to which I was not able to apply the solutions on my project.

I think this is a new question regarding this error on Xamarin.Forms. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: These errors are there too:

> Java.io.IOException:Connection refused
>
> Error accepting stdout and stderr (127.0.0.1:8944): Address already in use
>
> Could not load assembly 'FormsViewGroup' during startup registration.
>
> This might be due to an invalid debug instalation.
>
> A common cause is to 'adb install' the app directly instead of doing from the IDE.

I got the last error, although I launched the application from the IDE.

Comment: What emulator are you using? The Visual Studio Android Emulator, Google's Emulator or something like Genymotion?

Comment: I'm using BlueStacks. Here's its download link: http://www.bluestacks.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research this error commonly appears if you already have the app but a different version installed on the emulator.

If you delete all existing apps you have deployed to this emulator and try again that may work.

**Update**

1. Failing that I would create a brand new virtual device and make sure your API level is set correctly to what your app requires.
2. Try using the Visual Studio Android Emulator, it works really well and it is what I use.

Comment: It did not help. The same problem.

Comment: Check my edited question for a list of some other errors.

Comment: Updated my answer as well. The updated errors you have seem like you just need to restart your emulator, or reboot your PC and try again as a connection is either blocked by another process or the host on your emulator to accept incoming connections has failed and needs to be reconnected.

Comment: I rebooted my PC, then installed the Android Emulator and the HAXM accelerator. And you know what? It worked! Thanks a lot! I got really awesome one-to-one support from you, I never got such a good support! Thanks once again. I was not able to install the VS Android Emulator as it requires Win 10 Pro while I have Win 10 Home.